# How to speed up queries for 2m Datasets in PHP & Mysql

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

We have a SaaS Application site, where we would have over 2M records in a table.

```
Server version: 8.0.19 - MySQL Community Server - GPL
Protocol version: 10
```

Even with the indexes these queries are slow.

**My Question:**

1. Our Database query response in very slow in our PHP User Table Page. takes more than 4-5 mins to fetch the data. How can we improve the response time.
2. Our login page also respond slow to authenticate the user? How can we improve the performance?
3. Isn't our server good enough. Here is our specs (**Dedicated Server XL6 managed. CPU. AMD Hexa-Core. 6 Cores x 2.8 GHz. (3.3 GHz Turbo Core). RAM. 16 GB. DDR3 ECC. HDD. 1,000 GB (2 x 1,000 SATA))**

4.Would separating this table/data unto another database on a server
that has enough ram to store this data in memory would this speed up
these queries? Is there anything in anyway that the tables/indexes
are set up that we can improve upon to make these queries faster?

[image: Table Structure]

MySQL Table Information

```
Data    102.9   MiB
Index   10.2    MiB
Overhead    380 B
Effective   113.1   MiB
Total   113.1   MiB

Row statistics
Format  dynamic
Collation   latin1_swedish_ci
Rows    1,034,964
Row length  104 B
Row size    115 B
```

Comment: Show table's structure as complete CREATE TABLE script, not as screenshot. Show problematic query text and its execution plan. Specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: *where we would have over 2M records in a table*, but later *Rows    1,034,964* ???

Comment: @Akina - Will Add Create Table script and in the same table we would have 2M records, right we imported 1,034,964 records and stopped as the response time is slow.

Comment: How do your users authenticate(username, userid or other column)? Is that column indexed? What response times do you expect and how many rows do you expect to return?

Comment: We have used two query which are given below `SELECT * FROM user_tbl` to view all user list in dashboard and for [5:09 pm] simran
    
Sign In -
 `
SELECT*FROM user_tbl where (`EMAIL_ID` = '$username' OR `MOBILE` = '$username') AND `PWD` = '$pwd'

 `

Comment: 1. "select *": 
Never use this in Production code.  
2. "select * from user_tbl": 
What is your "dashboard" going to do with *2M* rows??  It would take ages just to display it and nobody in their right mind is going to scroll through that many rows, looking for a particular User.   You need to rethink this. 
3. "select * from user_tbl where ...": 
Are email_id and mobile indexed?  
*Please* tell me you're /not/ storing password in plain text!  
You are wide open to SQL Injection attacks.  Read up about PDO's Prepared Statements.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 0):

`OR` is un-optimizable.

```
SELECT*FROM user_tbl
    where  (EMAIL_ID = '$username'
              OR  MOBILE = '$username'
           )
      AND  PWD = '$pwd'
```

-->

```
SELECT * FROM user_tbl
    where  EMAIL_ID = '$username'
      AND  PWD = '$pwd' 
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT * FROM user_tbl
    where  MOBILE = '$username'
      AND  PWD = '$pwd'
```

and have these two *separate* indexes:

```
INDEX(email_id),
INDEX(mobile)
```

Meanwhile, `SELECT * FROM user_tbl` cannot be sped up.  Do you really need to show *all* the 1,034,964 rows and show *all* the columns?  Elaborate!  (See Phill's Comment.)